# How can one stop Sublime from closing groups?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

In Sublime Text 3, I divide my window once vertically and then the right pane once horizontally, for a total of 3 views.

When I close the last file in views 2 or 3, Sublime automatically closes the view, which is very annoying; I would like to preserve the empty view so I can open more files in it.

I can prevent this from happening with a single split by choosing View - Layout - Columns: 2, but this does not seem to work for additional splits.

How can I prevent Sublime from closing empty views?

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior using Build 3114. I used [`Origami`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami) to create the panes, typed some stuff in each one, then closed each tab without saving, and all three groups remain.

Comment: What do you have this preferences set to? `"close_windows_when_empty": false,`

Comment: @jwpfox I tried that, but it seems to affect only windows, not groups.

Comment: @MattDMo I'm on 3114 as well; starting from a clean window (and not using Origami) I can repro via: cmd-k + shift-cmd-up (new group) twice to split into 3, then ctrl-n to create a file and ctrl-w to close it.

Comment: @MattDMo I confirmed that Origami does not have the same behavior as vanilla; it works exactly as I asked for. Want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Weird, I'm experiencing the exact opposite of OP and desire the opposite as well. For me, groups remain open even after closing the last file that group. I am not using Origami, but it sounds like I should try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with multiple panes in a window, my go-to for several years now has been [`Origami`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami). There are menu items for all the options, but its real power is with the shortcuts. First press `super+k` (Windows and Linux use `ctrl` instead of `super`), then press the arrow keys with modifiers:

- `no modifiers`: travel to an adjacent pane
- `shift`: carry the current file to the destination
- `alt (option)`: clone the current file to the destination
- `super`: create an adjacent pane
- `super+shift`: destroy an adjacent pane

<sup>copied from the README</sup>

You can also zoom on the current pane and edit the pane sizes with the keyboard.

So how does all this help you? Well, when you close the final view in a pane, the pane stays open until *you* want to close (destroy) it.